# Pytest plugin errors

Tags: python, plugins, pytest

I have a plugin defined in root directory with addoption and configure in common_conftest.py
And in pytest.ini defined —addopts=—strict-marker

Now I have subdues test1 and test2.
In test1 I have defined conftest.py and also in test2

conftest.py
Import common_conftest
Pytest_plugins= common_conftest

And also in test1 and test2 I have defined run.sh
In test1
Pytest -c pytest.ini —rootdir  -v —option1

And similarly in test2 with corresponding option

Now when I run the .sh it is working fine because I imported but from rootdir when I run .sh it is giving defining plugins in non root directory is not supported error

I want a solution for above error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use plugin defined in rootdir in sub dir